# Async Javascript causes JS error function does not exist

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a jQuery script that I added an ASYNC attribute to. It seems to work OK in Firefox, but intermittently fails in Chrome and IE.

The PHP for loading adding the async attrib. This works fine:

```
function add_async_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   if ( substr($handle,0,3) !== 'jch' )
      return $tag;
   return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" src', $tag );
 }

 add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_attribute', 10, 2);
```

The JS file that causes a problem with the ASYNC attrib:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    jQuery('.home #intro_reel').jchTextReel( {fadeTime: 16000} );       
});

jQuery.fn.extend({

    jchTextReel: function(options) {                
        var defaults = {
                fadeTime: 10000,
                mouseOverColor : '#000000',
                mouseOutColor : '#ffffff'
        }

        var options =  jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

          return this.each(function() {
          var o = options;      

          ....etc....
```

Chrome shows an error 'jchTextReel is not a function'.

Again, removing the ASYNC attrib makes the script work OK again. OR, if I hit F5 to reload, the script seems to work.

Why? How do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

your file is being loaded asynchronously. when it is loaded, document ready is already triggered. that's why your top document ready is being executed immediately and calling **jchTextReel** which is not defined yet. to resolve it you need to first define **jchTextReel** then put the call. it seems firefox is ignoring **async** and loading the file synchronously but ie & chrome honoring async.

Answer (score 0):

`async` and `defer` are two separate boolean attributes. Doing `async="defer"` will set `async` to true, but `defer` is not set, so my guess is that sometimes the script is executing too soon. Here is a tweaked version of `add_async_attribute()` with distinct `async` and `defer` attributes:

```
function add_async_attribute($tag, $handle) {
    if ( substr($handle,0,3) !== 'jch' )
        return $tag;
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async defer src', $tag );
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_attribute', 10, 2);
```

Also, it's not shown in the original code posted, but the script that is being run uses jQuery, so `jquery` should be specified as a dependency for that script.

Comment: I made a TERRIBLE mistake in my code example. Please see the corrected version. It should have read 'async="async"' Sorry.

Comment: I tried your solution and no joy. Changing the return string to 'defer' does work, though.

Comment: That's okay. From what I've [gathered](https://css-tricks.com/async-attribute-scripts-bottom/), it's best to reserve the use of `async` for third party scripts due to the increased likelihood of dependency issues. So I'd drop it, and if these scripts are already in the footer (which is not clear from the code posted), defer is unnecessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case two approaches are possible.
1. Add `async="async"` and put `jQuery('.home #intro_reel').jchTextReel( {fadeTime: 16000} );` to the end of your file (`.js`)
2. Load the script from `.ready` handler. `async` attribute is not required in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {  
    $.getScript('path/to/script', function(){
       jQuery('.home #intro_reel').jchTextReel( {fadeTime: 16000} ); 
    });
});
```